# Is $\int \operatorname{sn}^2u\,\mathrm du$ really irreducible?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, elliptic-functions

Let $\operatorname{sn}$, $\operatorname{cn}$, $\operatorname{dn}$ be Jacobian elliptic functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/22). According to Greenhill,

> The integrals
> $$\operatorname{sn}^2u,\operatorname{cn}^2u,\operatorname{dn}^2u$$
> **require** for their expression new functions called elliptic integrals of the second kind, such as occur for instance in the rectification of the ellipse.

Can we prove that
$$\int \operatorname{sn}^2u\,\mathrm du,\ldots$$
**cannot** be expressed as a finite composition of elementary functions, elliptic functions and their inverses? This should be equivalent to proving that

1. the *Jacobi epsilon* (https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16#ii) cannot be expressed as a finite composition of elementary functions, elliptic functions and their inverses.
2. the elliptic integral of the second kind cannot be expressed as a finite composition of elemenetary functions, the elliptic integral of the first kind and its inverse.

It is interesting to note that the elliptic integral of the first kind can be expressed as a finite composition of elementary functions and the elliptic integral of the second kind, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#E4.

You can contrast this with, e.g.,
$$\int \operatorname{sn}(u,k)\,\mathrm du=-\frac{1}{k}\operatorname{artanh}(k\operatorname{cd}(u,k))+C$$
where no elliptic integrals of the second kind appear and where elementary functions and elliptic functions are sufficient.

Comment: We do have$$\int \! \left( {\rm sn} \left( u,k \right)  \right) ^{2}
\,{\rm d}u={\frac {u-{\it E} \left( {\rm sn} \left( u,k
 \right) ,k \right) }{{k}^{2}}}$$ so does this mean: if it **can** be expressed as you suggest, then the elliptic integral $E$ itself can be expressed that way?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Obviously yes. But how do we know that it is not the case? Greenhill doesn't prove his statement (hence this question).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: shouldn't it be $Arcsin(sn(u,k))$ instead of $sn(u,k)$ ?

Comment: The definition $$E(z,k) = \int_0^z\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt$$ (the Legendre form) as used by Maple.

Comment: also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4812103/87355